# Salesforce issue: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: xml, salesforce

I'm trying to get this code to work, but the error that comes up after running is:

> `XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.`

My code is:

```
<apex:page>
    <center>Log In And Lets Make Some Sales The World Is Yours.</center>
    <apex.form> <apex:commandbutton value="Log In" onClick="window.open('https://www.bluegreenvacations.com/');" /> </apex.form> 
 <apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you simply forgot the forward slash in line #4!?

```
</apex:page>
```